# 2 columns and a slider in one and it goes down

Tags: html, css

I have this CSS and HTML and every time the page zoom is used the slider goes down, and it's not visible in the column. Any help?

```
 .mask{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   margin: 0px auto;
   width: 96%;
   border: 5px solid #d2d3d6;
   max-height:320px;
}

.colleft{
   position: relative;
   width: 100%;
   right: 30%;
}

.col1{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   height:390px;
   left: 101%;
   background:url('../images/bg_rightt.jpg');
}

.col2{
   position: relative;
   overflow: hidden;
   float: left;
   width: 70%;
   height:390px;
   left: 1%;
   background-color: #f6f7f8;
}
```

and this html

```
  <div class="col2" style="border: 3px white solid;">
        <!-- Slider start -->
        <div class="slider-wrapper theme-default">

        <div id="slider" class="nivoSlider" style="width:100%; height:320px;">

            <img src="sliderimg/nivo1.jpg" data-thumb="" alt="" title="Aici se adauga text despre imaginea 1" />

            <img src="sliderimg/nivo2.jpg" data-thumb="" alt="" title="Aici se adauga text despre imaginea 2" />

            <img src="sliderimg/nivo3.jpg" data-thumb="" alt="" title="Aici se adauga text despre imaginea 3" />

            <img src="sliderimg/nivo4.jpg" data-thumb="" alt="" title="Aici se adauga text despre imaginea 4" />

            <img src="sliderimg/nivo5.jpg" data-thumb="" alt="" title="Aici se adauga text despre imaginea 5" />

       </div>

     </div>
```

Comment: Try to remove `overflow: hidden;` out of `col2`

Comment: How far a re you zooming? Is it a realistic zoom level or are you testing a waayyy out the edge case?

Comment: Assign position: fixed; to slider.